# how can I structure the code in such a way that if hundres of res. parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created API real time API for World Stock Markets.

Real Time API: http://www.yourtradelog.com/liveapi/world-markets

`res` parameter is in ajax, if api has hundred of data, how can i structure the code to reduce it?

AJAX code which i want to structure to reduce it. I have used two data in `res`:

```js
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"get",
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            url:"{{url('liveapi/world-markets')}}",
            data:{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(res){
                if(!res){
                    alert('Something went wrong')
                }else{

                    var output = document.getElementById("chg"),
                        nifty = document.getElementById("nifty"),
                        oldValue = parseInt(output.dataset.oldValue || "0");

                    output.className = "";
                    output.innerHTML = res.sensex.lastprice;
                    output.dataset.oldValue = res.sensex.lastprice;



                    oldValueNifty = parseInt(output.dataset.oldValue || "0");
                    nifty.className = "";
                    nifty.innerHTML = res.nifty_50.lastprice;
                    nifty.dataset.oldValueNifty = res.nifty_50.lastprice;

                  //  output.classList.add(res.nasdaq.lastprice > 0 ? "greenText" : "redText");
                    if (res.sensex.lastprice > oldValue) {
                        output.classList.add("greenText");
                    } else {
                        output.classList.add("redText");
                    }

                    $('#live_change').text("("+res.sensex.changed+")" );
                    $('#per_change').html('<b>'+res.sensex.perchange+'%</b>');



                    if (res.nifty_50.lastprice > oldValueNifty) {
                        nifty.classList.add("greenText");
                    } else {
                        nifty.classList.add("redText");
                    }

                    $('#nifty_live').text("("+res.nifty_50.changed+")" );
                    $('#nifty_change').html('<b>'+res.nifty_50.perchange+'%</b>');


                    if(res.sensex.changed > 0 || res.nifty_50.changed > 0) {
                        document.getElementById("live_change").className = "green";
                        document.getElementById("per_change").className = "green";

                        document.getElementById("nifty_live").className = "green";
                        document.getElementById("nifty_change").className = "green";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("live_change").className = "red";
                        document.getElementById("per_change").className = "red";

                        document.getElementById("nifty_live").className = "red";
                        document.getElementById("nifty_change").className = "red";

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },1000);
```

Comment: This is no ajax code.

Comment: this is ajax code... should i paste here all code? @LazarNikolic

Comment: why stringed zero? take `oldValue = +output.dataset.oldValue || 0;` instead.

Comment: Yes, because we cannot see ajax part. Where is fetching of data?

Comment: its giving me output as my expected. @NinaScholz how can i reduce my code if i used hundred of parameters?

Comment: where do you have the parameters?

Comment: if you got two nearly repeatung code parts, make a function and pass in the things that change as arguments. PS: what is `oldValueNifty` good for? you declare it but you don't use it.

Comment: i have added all my ajax code @NinaScholz

Comment: @lazar I don't think that the fetching part is relevant. I think it should be removed from the question completely as the question is about applying a datastructure to the pahes content.